# Signature Attribute Values in SAML 2.0

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, saml-2.0

I am in process of creating an SAML 2.0 response from IDP to SP. What I need is to get the values of the SAML 2.0 attributes from the certificate I got. Following are the SAML 2.0 attributes:

```
`<ds:SignatureValue> value from certificate </ds:SignatureValue>
 <ds:DigestValue> value from certificate </ds:DigestValue>
 `
```

And also can anybody guide me that what exactly are the steps I need to perform on SP side to successfully validate the generated SignatureValue form the given certificate.

Thanks!

Comment: What you need to do is to sign the response. Are you not using any framework or library for this? Just plain Java?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Oracle tutorial for how to validate XML digital signatures using the `java.xml.crypto.dsig` APIs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html

Unfortunately I did not have an easy time actually locating the code samples to download.  I did find one bit of the sample validation code [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/Validate.java).

Another good article is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).

At some point you'll need to obtain your SP's public key from the certificate and provide it to your validation code - that's covered in the tutorial under [using KeySelectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/xmldsig/XMLDigitalSignature.html#wp511424) section.  You can use the `keytool` command to extract from the certificate and add it to a keystore.  Sometimes this comes from key/certificate exchange offline; sometimes the key itself comes within the SAML document as X.509 data within`<KeyInfo>`.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer scotth. I am looking on to it .

Comment: I've looked into your answer and followed the links you mentioned. I have now successfully signed my SAML 2.0 xml document. But on SP side, I am unable to validate the signature. No matter what I try, I got exception : 
"org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key"

I am using openSAML for validation. I've loaded the keystore into my java code, got the certificate and extracted its public key and passed it along with my signature to validate, but no success. What can be missing here?

Comment: Excellent; I am glad it helped. If it led to the solution, please consider accepting it.